# Faster alternatives to csv and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have data augmentation code which requires appending to csv file. Data is in order of millions. It takes 2-3 days. Are there any faster alternatives? How fast is HDF5 in case where we need append operations in order of millions?

Edit: code: for reference only

```
def insert_data(directory, annotated_csv, output_csv):
    data = pd.read_csv(annotated_csv)
    data.to_csv(output_csv,index = False)
    counter = 0
    print("number of files: ", len(os.listdir(directory)))

    datachunk = []

    for fname in glob.glob(directory + '/*jpg'):



        fname = fname.split('/')[-1]

        counter = counter + 1

        if counter % 10000 == 0:
            df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(data=datachunk, columns=data.columns)

            df_tmp.to_csv(output_csv,mode = 'a', index = False, header=False)

            datachunk = []

            print("counter: "+ str(counter))


        try:    
            ofile = fname.split("-")[0]
            flabel = "'" + fname.split("-")[3] + "'"

            ofile = ofile +'.jpg'

            BB, MB, SB = get_all_bb(data, ofile)

            BB[0] = fname
            MB[0] = fname
            SB[0] = fname

            BB[7] = flabel
            MB[7] = flabel
            SB[7] = flabel

            datachunk.append(BB)
            datachunk.append(MB)
            datachunk.append(SB)

        except:
            print("Exception on"+ str(fname))
            pass

    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(data=datachunk, columns=data.columns)       
    df_tmp.to_csv(output_csv,mode = 'a', index = False, header=False)
    print("counter: "+ str(counter))
```

This code just gives a glimpse of what's happening.

Comment: and it wont work in a database?

Comment: @sammywemmy no it can't.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see what the slow part is? (I assume `get_all_bb`?) This looks embarrassingly parallel (just throw the for loop into `multiprocessing` and return `BB, MB, SB` triples from a processing function).

Comment: Also, instead of Pandas, try just append `pickle`d objects into a file (or files). You can then postprocess them into a CSV or whatever at your leisure.

Comment: @AKX it is a part of large code base. Main bottleneck is write operation. Constantly appending rows. Even after parallel processing, things are a bit slow

Comment: @meu Can you show us what `get_all_bb` does – or rather, why does it too need the `data` dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to save your data in `parquet` format (`pd.to_parquet(file_name, engine="pyarrow"`).
These are binary, compressed files which preserve the column data type.

A very nice property of parquet is that you can simply store multiple parquet files (with same columns) in a directory and open the whole directory at once.
These are called partitioned parquet stores and allow you lock-free appending of data.

Also you could consider working with PySpark as it is significantly faster on large datasets (query optimization, code generation and multi-processing for free).

Answer (score 0):

Using simple pandas will only utilize a single core of your CPU for computation.

**The solution:**

You could use **multiprocessing** combined with pandas in order to speed up this append computation. Using multiprocessing, you will be able to reduce the processing time depending on the number of cores of your CPU. The higher the number of cores of your machine, the lesser the processing time.

A sample implementation of multiprocessing using pandas can be referred from this link: http://datumorphism.com/til/programming/pandas/pandas-parallel-multiprocessing/

For more detailed explanation, you could refer to :
https://towardsdatascience.com/make-your-own-super-pandas-using-multiproc-1c04f41944a1